# MVC5 validation on email address client side

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I have the following property in my model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is a required field.")]
[StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "There are too many characters in this field.")]
[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
[EmailAddress]
[MaxLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Maximum of 150 characters allowed.")]
[Display(Name = "Customer budget owner")]
public string CustomerBudgetOwner { get; set; }
```

All the attributes are build-in ones from microsoft.
The html in the view looks like this:

```
 <div class="form-group">
  @Html.LabelFor(m => m.HardwareRequest.CustomerBudgetOwner, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-label" })
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon input-group-sm">
      <span>@@</span>
    </div>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.HardwareRequest.CustomerBudgetOwner, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control input-sm", id = "txtCustomerBudgetOwner" })
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <span id="btnCustomerBudgetOwnerInfo" class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign info-icon" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Enter the email address of the budget owner."></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.HardwareRequest.CustomerBudgetOwner, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

If I enter just a few characters but not the @ character, the validation error message is shown.

If I enter something like **aaaa@bbbbb.ccc** there is not error because it looks like an email address.

If I enter something like **aaaa@bbbbb** no client side error is shown, but in the controller the modelstate is not valid as it should be.

Did I make a mistake in the model validation attributes?
Or is it something else beyond my control?

[EDIT]
After removing the DataType attribute, the HTML generated looks like this:

```
<input class="form-control input-sm valid" data-val="true" data-val-email="The Customer budget owner field is not a valid e-mail address." data-val-length="There are too many characters in this field." data-val-length-max="150" data-val-maxlength="Maximum of 150 characters allowed." data-val-maxlength-max="150" data-val-required="Customer budget owner is a required field." id="txtCustomerBudgetOwner" name="HardwareRequest.CustomerBudgetOwner" type="text" value="" aria-required="true" aria-invalid="false" aria-describedby="txtCustomerBudgetOwner-error">
```

This is the value in the textbox: sdfsdfsdf@sdfsdfsdf

ModelState:

[image]

Comment: Does adding a `type = "email"` in your Razor declaration help? Granted, that's HTML5 compliant browsers only, but that should be a sizable chunk now.

Comment: You do not need either the `[DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]` or `[MaxLength]` attribute (which is already covered by the `[StringLength]` attribute. Client side validation works fine (refer [this DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QUW6o6)) and I cannot reproduce what your claiming

Answer (score -1):

I too have discovered this issue whereby the validation rules differ between client side and server side. It seems weird that given the data annotation is applied on the model you would expect consistent behaviour.

In saying that I am on the fence a bit - technically the client side validation is probably more accurate, but it is edge case.